# jquery ajax file upload , parameters to be sent

Tags: php, jquery

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Above is the line for a form to upload a file using php.

If i use the form as I wrote above I can get the various properties of the file to be uploaded from upload_file.php page.

Using jquery $.post , how can I do the same thing in upload_file.php ?

I googled but can't find the exact snippet of code necessary here.

Comment: U can look at source code of plupload

Comment: that should be difficult to understand.. I am just looking for the code snippet

Comment: from ajax's $.post it would be extremely difficult, i think what it does is create a iframe, set its stc attributes to the page upload_file.php , post it to the iframe and collect the resulting html and display it back, all using javascript. Somewhat like jerry answered. some people had their code to encode the file and grab the encoded string and upload using ajax but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading images using jquery's ajax methods is a pain, generally involving dynamically creating an iframe and submitting a form inside it. I usually use this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-upload

You can write some php to echo the uploaded image data as a json object, which you can access once the upload is complete through the plugin.

Comment: where to write the php code? ur addess says the  urlof .upload is the destination folder where as the 'views source' link in http://lagoscript.org/jquery/upload/demo?locale=en shows  a filename in the url... simply confused

Comment: When viewing source, it shows you that the demos are submitting to a file called "demo_upload.html". You should instead be directing it to "upload_file.php", and making sure that it echos the data you want back as a json object.